# Convert fbk (firebird) file to MySql

Tags: mysql, firebird

I have firebird database file and I want to convert it into Mysql, but I don't know how. Can you help me how to convert it? Or can you give me the reference what software I have to use to convert it?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You have to use [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/) tool to generate a dump with inserts

```
FBExport.exe -D "c:\DB\WL.FDB" -U user –P password -Si -V TEST -F test.out
Where: 
Si – means “export to SQL inserts” format
V – table name to export
F – output filename
```

Be careful with dates in mysql. Export in the correct format. To export db in custom date format use:

```
$> FBExport.exe -D "c:\DB\WL.FDB" -U user –P password -Si -V TEST -F     test.out -J "Y-M-D" -K "H:M:S"
Where: 
J  - date format
K – time format
```

To import date to mySQL use SOURCE command:

```
$> mysql --user=root --password=password
$> use  database_name
$> SOURCE  c:\export\table_name.out
```

Ref: http://kosiara87.blogspot.nl/2011/03/export-data-from-firebird-into-pure-sql.html