# Converting.fdb to MySQL with a Mac

Tags: mysql, firebird

Did anyone manage to convert or even just open a firebird .fdb file using a Mac?
I have a database file and I need to somehow parse the data into MySQL tables

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you have problems installing or using Firebird on a Mac, ask about that, although the Firebird-support mailinglist is probably a better venue for that type of question. Exporting data from Firebird to MySQL is not really a programming question, it might be more on topic on https://dba.stackexchange.com, but you really should do some research. Googling for "convert firebird mysql" alone already gives me a lot of tools, and even a question here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912165/convert-fbk-firebird-file-to-mysql

Answer (score 2):

For opening firebird databases on a mac you would need to run a firebird server... The simplest way of running firebird on a mac is via Docker. See https://hub.docker.com/r/jacobalberty/firebird/ for more details.

Then you could export your DDL via isql (the binary is in the docker container):

> isql DATABASE -o ddl.sql -x -u USER -p PASSWORD

But thats just the DDL!

For the Data you need to export the data as insert statements, like Mark Rotteveel commented on your question:
[Convert fbk (firebird) file to MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912165/convert-fbk-firebird-file-to-mysql)

Alternatively you could use a software like IBExpert for exporting the data. You can run IBExpert on a mac with wine.
http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/